# Enterprise Architect: Activity returns ParentID "0"

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm trying to loop up the hierarchy of an Enterprise Architect Model from a selected Node in JavaScript.
When I start with a Diagram within an Activity, the Diagram gives a valid `ParentID` (the Activity), but if I reach the Activity that returns 0 as a parent.
If I manually go up further to the Package containing the Activity I can cycle up to the Model Root.
So somehow all Activities in the Project return `ParentID` 0, all other times seem to return a valid `ParentID`  (apart from the Model of course, which is at the top).
Is there any chance to retrieve the Package Node within that the Activity is located?

Comment: Element.packageId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [EA.Element](https://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.2/automation/element2.html) will only have a `ParentID` with a value different from 0 if it is owned by another `EA.Element`.

If the element is owned by a package you have to use the `PackageID` to get the corresponding package. You can do that using the operation `EA.Repository.GetPackageByID()`

Comment: Thank you. In understand the Downvote, as the PackageID  was really next to ParentID.
Next challenge (If I should create a dedicated question I'm happy to do this): 
Some Elements are embedded in a Diagram, but are actually linked as a "Bevavior". I'm now interested in the Path of the behavior and of its parent/package. 
I can see an implementation which seems to solve this inside EAAddin.cs, but it is using UmlToolingFramework. 
I would prefer to stick with the built in Javascript and have no external depencies. Is this possible then?

Comment: @user2144067 yeah, I can't really answer that in a comment, so you better ask a proper new question. Make sure to state exactly what you need, what you tried, and where you got stuck. And don't forget to include your code as well.